# How to read the single characters from a hex (bytes string) in Python?

Tags: python, string, hex, hbase, pyspark

The question in the title might not reflect what I exactly want... I will try my best here.

I have the following representation of a hex string as string of bytes:

s='\x00\x00\x01b?\x90bM\xe0\x00\x00\x00'

I have an hbase table where the row key is in the same format of 's'.  But when I pass the range in this format would generate an error: **"utf-8 cannot decode byte..."**

sparkconf = {"hbase.zookeeper.quorum": "myHostIP","hbase.mapreduce.inputtable": "myHbaseTable","hbase.mapreduce.scan.columns": "c1:c2", "hbase.mapreduce.scan.row.start": startRow, "hbase.mapreduce.scan.row.stop": endRow}

it seems that startRow and endRow have to be strings of characters?

if so, is there a way to format/convert s='\x00\x00\x01b?\x90bM\xe0\x00\x00\x00' to a string of SAME charaters?

By this, I do not mean convert Hex t string, I mean I would need a string such as **str_s=MAKESTRING(s)** would result in **str_s='\x00\x00\x01b?\x90bM\xe0\x00\x00\x00'** where **str_s[0]='\', str_s[1]='x', str_s[2]='0' etc...**

Many thanks for the help, I am new to python, pyspark and hbase.

Comment: Where does your string come from? Do you generate it somehow?

Comment: yes, the first 4 bytes are an int and the last 8 a double.  So, the exact problem is:  It is not clear how hbase_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat","org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable","org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result",keyConverter=keyConv,valueConverter=valueConv,conf=sparkconf)
is interpreting the start and end row.  I have resolved the utf-8 issue as follows:
s=u'\x00\x00\x01b?\x90bM\xe0\x00\x00\x00' 
s=s.encode('utf-8')
but I am getting empty set from the range scan!
Thanks for helping

Comment: when I use the same ranges (start and end) with same format from hbase shell within a scan it works, not with newAPIHadoopRDD though!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use something like the following:

```
def printable_repr(s):
    """ Convert to a printable representation.

    Replace each nonprintable ascii byte in s by its 
    hex representation (\xXX)
    """
    printable_s = []
    for c in s:
        if 32 <= ord(c) and ord(c) <= 126:
            printable_s.append(c)
        else:
            printable_s.append("\\%02x" % ord(c))
    return ''.join(printable_s)


s = '\x00\x00\x01b?\x90bM\xe0\x00\x00\x00'
s_str = printable_repr(s)

print("s_str: " + s_str)

for i in range(0, len(s_str)):
    print(str(i) + ": " + s_str[i])
```

The script produces this output (Python 3.4.2):

```
s_str: \00\00\01b?\90bM\e0\00\00\00
0: \
1: 0
2: 0
3: \
4: 0
5: 0
6: \
7: 0
8: 1    
9: b
10: ?   
11: \
12: 9
13: 0
14: b
15: M
16: \
17: e
18: 0
19: \
20: 0
21: 0
22: \
23: 0
24: 0
25: \
26: 0
27: 0
```

Of course you can easily simplify the script if you would like to also replace the printable ascii characters by their hex representation.